# select the extra row data

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table sample, I had deleted a lot column.

```
id  orid    to_id   seq
1   1       5       A12
2   2       6       A12
3   3       7       A12
4   4       _       A12 <--- I want to find this row
5   5       _       A13
6   6       _       A13
7   7       _       A13
```

I want to find the extra data. I want use this two SQL to find extra data.

```
(select * from ForgeRock where seq = 'A13') a
(select * from ForgeRock where seq != 'A13') b
```

I had tried it, but not my wanted. How can I do it? Thanks.

```
select b.* from 
  (select * from ForgeRock where seq = 'A13') a
right join 
  (select * from ForgeRock where seq != 'A13') b
on a.to_id = b.to_id;
```

This is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3279d/5)

Comment: What is the definition of `4   4       _       A12` being extra row ?

Comment: what do you want to find out. rows with same values.?

Comment: id 1~4 is same group by seq, id 5~6 is same group by seq to, but now 1~3 is copy  insert as 5~6, the id 4 is later create, so I want to find it and create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This is I want, and this is my code.

```
select b.* from
  (select * from ForgeRock where seq = 'A13') a
right join 
  (select * from ForgeRock where seq != 'A13') b
on a.id = b.to_id
where b.to_id = '_';
```

This is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3279d/17)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to find rows that have no connection to another row.

```
select fr.*
from ForgeRock fr
where fr.to_id is NULL and
      not exists (select 1
                  from ForgeRock fr2
                  where fr.from_id = fr2.to_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL will useful to you.

```
select * from ForgeRock where orid =
(select max(orid) from ForgeRock where seq ='A12') ;
```

Thank you.